# How to read Json files in a directory separately with a for loop and performing a calculation

Tags: python, json, for-loop

Update: Sorry it seems my question wasn't asked properly. So I am analyzing a transportation network consisting of more than 5000 links. All the data included in a big CSV file. I have several JSON files which each consist of subset of this network. I am trying to loop through all the JSON files INDIVIDUALLY (i.e. not trying to concatenate or something), read the JSON file, extract the information from the CVS file, perform calculation, and save the information along with the name of file in new dataframe. Something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQTbv.jpg)

This is the code I wrote, but not sure if it's efficient enough.

```
name=[]
percent_of_truck=[]
path_to_json = \\directory
import glob
z= glob.glob(os.path.join(path_to_json, '*.json'))

for i in z:

    with open(i, 'r') as myfile:
        l=json.load(myfile)
        name.append(i) 
        d_2019= final.loc[final['LINK_ID'].isin(l)] #retreive data from main CSV file
        avg_m=(d_2019['AADTT16']/d_2019['AADT16']*d_2019['Length']).sum()/d_2019['Length'].sum() #calculation
        percent_of_truck.append(avg_m)

f=pd.DataFrame()
f['Name']=name
f['% of truck']=percent_of_truck
```

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to the community. Please edit your post to provide more details like structure of your json and any code you have done so far. Also mention what is the exact problem you are facing. That would be helpful to identify the solution.

Comment: Please, take [tour] and check [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here you just want a dictionary of all the JSON. If so, use the JSON library ( `import JSON`). If so, this code may be of use:

```
import json

def importSomeJSONFile(f):
    return json.load(open(f))
 
# make sure the file exists in the same directory

example = importSomeJSONFile("example.json")

print(example)

 #access a value within this , replacing key with what you want like "name"

print(JSON_imported[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't added any Schema or any other specific requirements.

You can follow this approach to solve your problem, in  any language you prefer

1. Get Directory of the JsonFiles, which needs to be read
2. Get List of all files present in directory
3. For each file-name returned in Step2.

   1. Read File
   2. Parse Json from String
   3. Perform required calculation